# Regex replacement problem, negative lookahead not behaving as expected

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write some replacement regex that will insert a locale code into a url if it doesn't already exist. I'm usig the negative lookahead pattern to achieve this shown below

```
(^http://.*?/)(?!en/|\w{2}\-\w{2}/)(?<path>.*?$)
```

So i want to match everything up to the first forward slash, then check that a locale does not exist. Locales can be either 'en' or the usual 'en-GB' style locale code in our site. Currently this pattern will do the following:

http://www.mywebsite.com/location/index.html => http://www.mywebsite.com/en/location/index.html
http://www.mywebsite.com/en/location/index.html => http://www.mywebsite.com/en/en/location/index.html

using the following replacement pattern: $1en/${path}

So the first one works correctly, but the second one matches even though i don't want it to and then puts the locale code in anyway.

Is what i want to do possible, it sounds like it should be. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: What programming language/regex dialect are you using? .NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the first `.*?` with `[^/]*`.

For example:
`^(http://[^/\s]*/)(?!en/|\w{2}-\w{2}/)(?<path>\S*)$`

Answer (score 1):

"i want to match everything up to the first forward slash, then check that a locale does not exist."

What this `(^http://.*?/)(?!en/|\w{2}\-\w{2}/)(?<path>.*?$)` does is match everything up
to the first forward slash that doesent have a `en` in front of it.

Its different than matching up to the first forward slash, then fail if `en` is in front of it.

The regex will always try to succede taking the shortest path. Even though it acts ungreedy using the ?, it will actually keep going until it satisfies the anchor or condition trailing it. In this case it found a forward slash without `en` in front of it: `www.mywebsite.com/en/` and that is not the first forward slash, its the second.

This is a gotcha, it happens all the time and is something to note for the future.
So the goal would be to restrain it to match the FIRST forward slash: `[^/]*/`

Comment: Thanks for the really detailed explanation on that one, i'll have to try and remember this for future.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regular expression instead:

```
^(http://[^\/]+/)(?!en/|\w{2}\-\w{2}/)(?<path>.*)$
```

Comment: did you mean to include the ~ on either end, it doesn't seem to work if you do

Comment: ~ was used as delimeter only for regular expression and if you want I can show you a working code demo on ideone.

Comment: Edited my answer to remove confusing `~` (that I used for my testing).